# Яндекс.API Передача значения из переменной в iconContent метки

Tags: yandex-maps-api

Есть скрип который в массив value берёт значения координат из таблицы и перемещает метку по заданным координатам, в переменную name берёт название метки.
Подскажите пожалуйста, как передать данные из переменной name в iconContent метки вместе с координатами.

```
ymaps.ready(init);

function init() {
    // Создание карты.
    var myMap = new ymaps.Map("map", {
        // Координаты центра карты.Порядок по умолчнию: «широта, долгота».
        center: [55.76, 37.64],
        // Уровень масштабирования. Допустимые значения: от 0 (весь мир) до 19.
        zoom: 9
    }, {
        // Поисковая строка
        searchControlProvider: 'yandex#search'
    });


    // Переменная для координат
    var value = [], address = [];
    // Берём координаты из таблицы
    if (document.getElementById('geoTable')) {
        address[1] = document.getElementById('geoTable').rows[1].cells[2].textContent;
        address[0] = document.getElementById('geoTable').rows[1].cells[3].textContent;
    // Координаты по умолчанию
    } else {
        address = [55.7, 37.6];
    };

    // Перемещение метки на заданные координаты при нажатии кнопки "Перейти"
    var button = document.getElementById("geoButton");
        geoButton.onclick = geoByValue;

    // Перемещение метки на координаты из таблицы
    var tds = document.getElementsByTagName('td');
    for (var i = 0; i < tds.length; i++)
    tds[i].onclick = function() {
        var tr = this.parentNode;
        var name = tr.getElementsByTagName('td')[1].innerHTML;
        value[1] = tr.getElementsByTagName('td')[2].innerHTML;
        value[0] = tr.getElementsByTagName('td')[3].innerHTML;
        address = value;
        console.log(name)
        document.getElementById('geomapy').value = value[0];
        document.getElementById('geomapx').value = value[1];
        myGeoObject.geometry.setCoordinates(address);
        console.log(value)
    };

    // Метка по заданным координатам
    function geoByValue() {
        value[1] = Number(document.getElementById("geomapx").value);
        value[0] = Number(document.getElementById("geomapy").value);
        address = value;
        myGeoObject.geometry.setCoordinates(address);
        console.log(value)
    };
        console.log(value)
        myGeoObject = new ymaps.GeoObject({
            geometry: {
                type: "Point",
                coordinates: address
            },
            properties: {
                iconContent: name,
                balloonContent: 'Меня можно перемещать'
            },
        }, {
            preset: 'islands#redStretchyIcon',
            draggable: true
    });

    // Добавление координат в форме создания записи в БД
    var addCoordToDB;
        if(document.getElementById('addGeo')) {
            addCoordToDB = document.getElementById('addGeo');
            addCoordToDB.onclick = function() {
            var longitude = Number(document.getElementById("geomapx").value);
            var latitude = Number(document.getElementById("geomapy").value);
            document.getElementById('longitude').value = longitude;
            document.getElementById('latitude').value = latitude;
        }
    };

    // Обработка события, возникающего при щелчке
    // левой кнопкой мыши в любой точке карты.
    myMap.events.add('click', function (e) {
        var coords = e.get('coords');
        value[1] = coords[1].toPrecision(8),
        value[0] = coords[0].toPrecision(8),
        address = value
        document.getElementById('geomapy').value = value[0];
        document.getElementById('geomapx').value = value[1];
        myGeoObject.geometry.setCoordinates(address);
    });

    myGeoObject.events.add("dragend", function (e) {
        var coords = e.get('target').geometry.getCoordinates();
        document.getElementById('geomapy').value = coords[0].toPrecision(8);
        document.getElementById('geomapx').value = coords[1].toPrecision(8);
    });

    myMap.geoObjects.add(myGeoObject);}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
ymaps.ready(init);

function init() {
    // Создание карты.
    var myMap = new ymaps.Map("map", {
        // Координаты центра карты.Порядок по умолчнию: «широта, долгота».
        center: [55.76, 37.64],
        // Уровень масштабирования. Допустимые значения: от 0 (весь мир) до 19.
        zoom: 9
    }, {
        // Поисковая строка
        searchControlProvider: 'yandex#search'
    });


    // Переменная для координат
    var value = [], address = [];
    var name;
    // Берём координаты из таблицы
    if (document.getElementById('geoTable')) {
        name = document.getElementById('geoTable').rows[1].cells[1].innerHTML;
        address[1] = document.getElementById('geoTable').rows[1].cells[2].textContent;
        address[0] = document.getElementById('geoTable').rows[1].cells[3].textContent;
    // Координаты по умолчанию
    } else {
        address = [55.7, 37.6];
    };

    // Перемещение метки на заданные координаты при нажатии кнопки "Перейти"
    var button = document.getElementById("geoButton");
        geoButton.onclick = geoByValue;

    // Перемещение метки на координаты из таблицы
    var tds = document.getElementsByTagName('td');
    for (var i = 0; i < tds.length; i++)
    tds[i].onclick = function() {
        var tr = this.parentNode;
        name = tr.getElementsByTagName('td')[1].innerHTML;
        value[1] = tr.getElementsByTagName('td')[2].innerHTML;
        value[0] = tr.getElementsByTagName('td')[3].innerHTML;
        address = value;
        console.log(name)
        document.getElementById('geomapy').value = value[0];
        document.getElementById('geomapx').value = value[1];
        myGeoObject.properties.set("iconContent", name);
        myGeoObject.geometry.setCoordinates(address);
        console.log(value)
    };

    // Метка по заданным координатам
    function geoByValue() {
        value[1] = Number(document.getElementById("geomapx").value);
        value[0] = Number(document.getElementById("geomapy").value);
        address = value;
        myGeoObject.geometry.setCoordinates(address);
        console.log(value)
    };
        console.log(value)
        myGeoObject = new ymaps.GeoObject({
            geometry: {
                type: "Point",
                coordinates: address
            },
            properties: {
                iconContent: name,
                balloonContent: 'Меня можно перемещать'
            },
        }, {
            preset: 'islands#redStretchyIcon',
            draggable: true
    });

    // Добавление координат в форме создания записи в БД
    var addCoordToDB;
        if(document.getElementById('addGeo')) {
            addCoordToDB = document.getElementById('addGeo');
            addCoordToDB.onclick = function() {
            var longitude = Number(document.getElementById("geomapx").value);
            var latitude = Number(document.getElementById("geomapy").value);
            document.getElementById('longitude').value = longitude;
            document.getElementById('latitude').value = latitude;
        }
    };

    // Обработка события, возникающего при щелчке
    // левой кнопкой мыши в любой точке карты.
    myMap.events.add('click', function (e) {
        var coords = e.get('coords');
        value[1] = coords[1].toPrecision(8),
        value[0] = coords[0].toPrecision(8),
        address = value
        document.getElementById('geomapy').value = value[0];
        document.getElementById('geomapx').value = value[1];
        myGeoObject.geometry.setCoordinates(address);
    });

    myGeoObject.events.add("dragend", function (e) {
        var coords = e.get('target').geometry.getCoordinates();
        document.getElementById('geomapy').value = coords[0].toPrecision(8);
        document.getElementById('geomapx').value = coords[1].toPrecision(8);
    });

    myMap.geoObjects.add(myGeoObject);
    }
```